# Creating a RNN dataset and model for understanding context of a sports event

Tags: neural-network, tensorflow, time-series, dataset, rnn

I'm working on a project which requires my code to understand what is happening at any instant in a video feed of a sports match. For example, take a football match. At a given moment, my code focuses around the area where the ball is currently being played. Now, if a player A of team X passes the ball to player B of the same team X, the code must know that the ball has been passed succesfully to a teammate. However, if a player C from the opposite team Y intercepts this pass, the code must know that too. Similarly for other significant events of a football match such as a goal being scored, foul being committed etc.

I was thinking I would need to implement a RNN model whose training dataset consists of individual frames of previously recorded matches of the same sport, and for predictions, pass about 5 seconds of video (split into frames) and get the output as the event that just occured (like ball passed succesfully, ball tackled, goal scored etc)

But I am not very clear on how this dataset should look like. Like, when converted to a csv file, what should be the columns. I am also not clear how to pass the inputs for predictions (which will ofcourse depend on the format of the dataset).

Can someone help me understand howto build a model for this? And there is some other logic which could work better than mine, or uses a model other that RNN, can you share that ?

Comment: This question seems to be more about how to create a dataset than about the model.

Comment: I guess it's a bit of both, but I suppose it's a bit more inclined towards creating a dataset, I'll edit the title